# Can't kill celery processes started by Supervisor

Tags: celery, supervisord

I am running a VPS on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.04.

I setup supervisor to run a bash script to export environment vars and then start celery:

```
#!/bin/bash

DJANGODIR=/webapps/myproj/myproj

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate

export REDIS_URL="redis://localhost:6379"

...

celery -A connectshare worker --loglevel=info --concurrency=1
```

Now I've noticed that supervisor does not seem to be killing these processes when I do supervisorctl stop. Furthermore, when I try to manually kill the processes they won't stop. How can I set up a better script for supervisor and how can I kill the processes that are running?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending `kill -9` have to kill process. If `supervisorctl stop` doesn't stop your process you can try setting up `stopsignal` to one of other values, for example `QUIT` or `KILL`.

You can see more in [supervisord documentation](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=stopsignal#program-x-section-settings).

Comment: Also worth noting, I had to switch to the user that started the process in order to kill it.

Answer (score 13):

You should configurate the `stopasgroup=true` option into `supervisord.conf` file.

Because you just not only kill the parent process but also the child process.

Comment: Worked for me but intsead of adding in supervisord.conf i had to add it to the [program:] configs in conf.d.

Comment: @elGEoRgETheKiLLa Yeah. Wish it could help you figure it out.